# add featured image dialog box disappear

Tags: database, post-thumbnails

I have a test site [here](http://www.patricetourenne.fr/wp-testsite/academie-sophro-v2/publications_type/publications/) (with WordPress 3.2.1)

Since I activate the multisite support, the **add featured image** disappear. I try to deactivate all the plugin and activate the **default theme** (twenty eleven with has add_theme_support ('post-thumbnail') by default) but nothing change. 
The post thumbnail show up normaly on the **front** but I can't edit them without this dialog box. Of course, I checked on the "option" tab and nothing appear too for the post thumbnail feature.

---

**When I use WP_DEBUG, I get:**

Notice: register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_sidebar_widget() instead. in /home/patricet/public_html/wp-testsite/academie-sophro-v2/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3382

Notice: has_cap is called with an argument which is deprecated since version 2.0! The use of levels of user extensions and themes now prohibited. Use roles and capabilities in place. in / home/patricet/public_html/wp-testsite/academie-sophro-v2/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3466

**In console (with Firebug) for .js I get:**

The use of the property "nodeValue" of an attribute is deprecated. Use "value" instead

---

**I can create an editor account if you need**

Do you have a solution, an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Try disabling plugins to see if it re-appears, also can you let us know if there are any errors in your JS console or your PHP error log?

Comment: Thanks Tom. Like I said I disable already all the plugin and it change nothing. For the errors I will add to the the thread right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution. The problem start when I activate the multi site on the test site. In the network setting, in Upload Settings  Everything works now.

Comment: Please mark your answer as **The Answer**. We have enough unanswered questions here. :)